# Ruby: Establish client connection on particular URI path with ruby TCPSocket

Tags: ruby, sockets, websocket, tcpserver, tcpsocket

With Ruby [TCPSocket](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPSocket.html) I can do something like this:

```
@socket = TCPSocket.new "174.129.224.73", 80
```

which corresponds to test echo websocket `ws://echo.websocket.org`

But what if I need to establish connection with the socket based on

```
domain:10440/api/websockets
```

How do I do this with TCPSocket?

Comment: A TCPSocket and a Websocket are different things with a bit of similar behavior, similar names and different usage. WebSockets are actually a connection inside a HTTP(S) connection which itself is a TCP connection.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich this explains a lot. I established TCP connection tho the socket and then made websocket requests to particular path and it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put a bit more context to Steffen Ullrich's answer:

This can't be done in the way you imagine (or ask) it to be done.

The part of the URL you are asking about (`/the/path`) - known as the URI, "**U**nique **R**esource **I**dentifier" - is HTTP specific and isn't applicable for all TCP/IP connections.

The URI is usually requested AFTER the TCP connection is made, in accordance to the HTTP protocol (using any of the HTTP methods such as the HEAD, GET, POST etc').

The Websocket protocol uses an HTTP method called "UPGRADE" which asks the server to switch from the HTTP protocol to the Websocket protocol.

During this UPGRADE request, the resource requested is requested using it's URI. At `ws://echo.websocket.org`, the resource is at the root - `/`, but it could be anywhere and identify different websockets, such as using `/echo` for echo and `/chat` for a different web-app application.

You can see for yourself that the following line isn't connected to the websocket echo server:
    @socket = TCPSocket.new "174.129.224.73", 80

`@socket` is now connected to the HTTP server, and the websocket connection hadn't been established yet.

see what response you get for:

```
require 'socket'
@socket = TCPSocket.new "174.129.224.73", 80
@socket << "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"
@socket.read 1024
@socket.close
```

As you can see, you get an HTTP response.

```
# @socket.read(1024) # => should return "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nContent-Length: 61\r\n\r\n<html><head></head><body><h1>404 Not Found</h1></body></html>"
```